# Why doesn't the src attribute of an iframe change if I click on any link inside it?

Tags: html, browser

In the following code the **src** attribute of iframe always shows b.html in devtools insepct, even after clicking on the link in the **b.html** page

**index.html**

```html
<html>
  <body>
   <iframe src="b.html">
   </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

**b.html**

```html
<html>
  <body>
   <a href="d.html">link</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

**d.html**

```html
<html>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spec doesn't appear to explain why this is the case, other than by stating that the `WindowProxy` operates independently of the element itself (for what it's worth). It does confirm that this is expected behavior ([W3C HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-iframe-element), [WHATWG HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iframe-embed-object.html#the-iframe-element)):

> If the user navigates away from this page, the `iframe`’s corresponding `WindowProxy` object will proxy new `Window` objects for new `Document` objects, but the `src` attribute will not change.

Comment: @Kaiido: Yeah, I guess that's what I meant to say: "the only way to change an img's src is by changing the attribute directly."

Comment: @Kaiido: That's frustrating. I think I'll just delete the last paragraph - it's speculative anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As [@BoltClock said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50691820), the `src=` attribute of the iframe doesn't change but you can get the new url of the iframe by accessing its

```
 document.getElementById('my-iframe').contentWindow.location.href
```

but your iframe has to be on the same domain as the page hosting it.